# Как выполняется сортировка, при операции UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть два простых запроса с операцией `UNION`

```
SELECT
    'query_1' AS marker,
    id
FROM test_t
ORDER BY id

UNION

SELECT
    'query_2' AS marker,
    id
FROM test_t
ORDER BY id
```

Гарантирует ли `MySQL` в данном случае, что после операции `UNION`, записи будут отсортированы в порядке выполнения запроса?
То есть, результат мне нужен такой:

```
marker    | id
--------------
'query_1' | 1
'query_1' | 2
 ... - остальные записи из первого запроса
'query_2' | 1
'query_2' | 2
 ... - остальные записи из второго запроса
```

Comment: ЕМНИП никакой порядок не гарантирован даже при простом `SELECT`, если вы не добавите сами `ORDER BY`

Comment: Операции UNION (без ALL) надо как минимум найти дубликаты строк что бы их выбросить. А это группировка. А группировка выполняется сортировкой. так что ваш порядок будет сбит. Но даже если вы добавите ALL, то SQL ничего не гарантирует. Необходимо написать один общий ORDER BY на весь запрос. При необходимости в сами запросы можно добавить колонку, которая в первом запросе будет 1, во втором 2. и использовать ее в сортировке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в [официальной документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) сказано:

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.

т.е. ORDER подзапросов не влияет на результат UNION'а. Там же написано, что если в подзапросах не используется LIMIT, то ORDER выбрасывается оптимизатором.

Сортировку нужно применять к результату объединения, например так:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'query_1' AS marker, id FROM test_t
  UNION
  SELECT 'query_2' AS marker, id FROM test_t
) A
ORDER BY marker, id
```